# Finding The Area of a Circle With Calculus

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits, trigonometry, circles

This is my first attempt to actually go ahead and prove the area of a circle is $\pi r^2$ using the methods shown on calculus. I first used a coordinate system and placed the centre of my circle (with radius $r$) at the origin. Now, we increase the number of sides of the inscribed regular polygon; we note that the number of sides (call it $n$) is the same as the number of isosceles triangle “sectors” that the polygon consists of. If the angle of each of these triangles is $\theta$, then the base of each triangle  (or equivalently, one side of the regular polygon) is easily seen to be $r\sin\theta \over \cos\frac{\theta}{2}$. The apothem of the regular polygon is easily seen to be $r\cos\frac{\theta}{2}$. So that the area of each isosceles triangle “sector” is $\frac{1}{2}r^2\sin\theta$. Since there are $n$ triangles, the area of the whole polygon $\frac{1}{2}r^2\sin\theta n$. This can be used as the function take the limit of as it’s variable approaches infinity, however, it has two variables $\theta$ and $n$. So we rewrite $\theta$ as a function of $n$, which is $\theta = –\frac{\pi}{8} n$. Hence our function is $f(n) = – \frac{r^2\sin(\frac{\pi}{8})n}{2}$. This is where I am stumped. I need to find $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)$. However, the limit of $\sin x$ as $x$ approaches infinity is undefined. How do you continue from this point on? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please include some visuals for your proof attempt, as of right now it is very hard to follow your thought process without them.

Comment: If your polygon is divided into $n$ triangles and the area of each of them is $\frac12r^2\sin\theta$, then the area of the polygon is $\frac n2r^2\sin\theta$, rather than $\frac12r^2\sin(n\theta)$.

Comment: $\theta=\frac{2\pi}{n}$

Comment: You are trying to find the area of the circle *without* using calculus, and using inscribed or circumscribed polygons instead.  If, as your *question* states, you want to use the calculus, then you don't need the approximating polygons.  The calculation is immediate in polar coordinates, and even in Cartesian coordinates it is significantly easier than what you've tried.

Comment: @MikhailKatz I thoroughly believe that the notion of a limit is introduced only during calculus. Am I not here trying to find the limit of a function, hence how does the method not pertain calculus?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos yes, that's what I meant to type, there must have been a typo in the post

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I believe I understood how to prove it. However, could someone explain why $lim_{n\implies ∞}n sin\frac{\pi}{n} = \pi$?

Comment: Because\begin{align}\lim_{n\to\infty}n\sin\frac n\pi&=\pi\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sin(\pi/n)}{\pi/n}\\&=\pi.\end{align}

Comment: @Camelot823 But you get to the result much faster via integration, which is certainly part of the Calculus since at least the 17th century :-)